# Convert CsvReader to SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, .net-core

With this C# method I can read from a `.csv` file into a list of contracts where CsvHelper works great through it's field mapper.

```
    public static List<Contract> readDataFile(string filePath)
    {
        List<Contract> contracts = new List<Contract> { };

        using var reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) {
            Delimiter = ";",
            PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.ToLowerInvariant()
        };

        using var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, config);
        {
            csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap<ContractMap>();
            IEnumerable<Contract> dataContracts = csvReader.GetRecords<Contract>();

            foreach (Contract c in dataContracts)
            {
                contracts.Add(c);
            }
        }
    }
```

Like that I would like to convert it to a `SqlDataReader` but that does not have a `GetRecords` with a mapper for `<T>`. I am quite new to .NET Core and was searching around. It's not clear what the right approach is.

So thanks for any hint !

Is there some generic way for `SqlDataReader` to convert to a given object?

Clarification

This code works fine !  There no change needed. It's just that the csv data comes now from a DB. Query the DB works also. I simply search a neat way of reading the same data through SQLReader into the same list.

Comment: That sounds like a job for [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

Comment: thanks for your correction and mentioning Dapper. So there is no "native" ORM for SQLDataReader in Dotnet ?

Comment: Why do you want it specifically as a `SqlDataReader`? Would a `DbDataReader`/`IDataReader` be sufficient? It looks like `CsvDataReader : IDataReader`, if you mean the CsvHelper here: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvDataReader.cs

Comment: @user3732793 define "native"; the BCL only covers System.Data, which doesn't even include `SqlDataReader` - that's now moved out to either `System.Data.SqlClient` (an auxiliary nuget package, *not* the core framework) or `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` (notably: as two completely different implementations); as for ORMs: Microsoft provide EF for first-party, but whether that is "native" is ... complex; many non-Microsoft tools are available.

Comment: additional question: it looks like the `GetRecords<T>` API is part of `CsvReader` - so... why do you not just use that directly?

Answer (score 4):

You can't get a `SqlDataReader`, because `SqlDataReader` is **specifically** a `SqlClient` implementation talking to SQL Server, which: you're not. You *can* get an `IDataReader`, though: assuming you're talking about [this CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/), there is a `CsvDataReader` that takes a `CsvReader` instance in the constructor, and which implements `IDataReader`. That should be enough for most common scenarios (although it would arguably be preferable if it derived from `DbDataReader`). It would, for example, be sufficient for use with Dapper, via:

```cs
using var dataReader = new CsvDataReader(csvReader);
var deserializer = SqlMapper.GetTypeDeserializer(typeof(Contract), dataReader);
while (dataReader.ReadNext())
{
    var c = (Contract)deserializer(dataReader);
    // whatever you want to do with that
}
```

---

If you mean you want to just use something *like* `GetRecords<T>` but with `SqlDataReader` instead of `CsvHelper` (taking `CsvHelper` out of things entirely): then - just about any ORM would work. You'd probably let the ORM worry about the data-reader part too, though; for example (again, I'm using Dapper here for convenience):

```cs
using var conn = // ... create a connection
string region = ...
var data = conn.Query<Contact>(
    "select * from Contacts where Region=@region", // sql
    new { region } // parameters
).AsList();
```

---

Or in something like EF via LINQ:

```cs
string region = ...
var data = dbContext.Contacts.Where(x => x.Region == region).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for that. The later looks promissing